# Port forwarding issue (I think)

Tags: networking, router, dns, port-forwarding

I made a very basic KryoNet server and client program. If I connect the client through localhost it works as expected. Now I want to connect to it from outside so I have setup a DNS for myself with the dynamic DNS tool from noip.com. When I connect through the DNS the correct IP is shown by KryoNet but it does not connect.

Server:

```
public class ServerTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Server server = new Server();
        server.start();
        server.bind(TCP, UDP);

        server.getKryo().register(Packet.class);
        server.getKryo().register(TestPackage.class);

        server.addListener(new Listener() {
            public void received (Connection connection, Object object)
            {
                if (object instanceof Packet)
                {
                    if (object instanceof TestPacket)
                    {
                        TestPacket p1 = (TestPacket) object;
                        System.out.println("server received: " + p1.name);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Client:

```
public class ClientTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Client client = new Client();
        client.start();
        try {
            client.connect(5000, "my.dynamic.dns", TCP, UDP);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Could not connect to server");
        }

        client.getKryo().register(Packet.class);
        client.getKryo().register(TestPacket.class);

        TestPacketp1 = new TestPacket();
        p1.name = "Menno Gouw";     
        client.sendTCP(p1);
    }
}
```

I forwarded the ports I used for TCP and UDP on my router. Not sure if there is a security risk in showing the ports so I just make some up for this question. I forwarded the ports for both my IPv4 address I get from ipconfig and my real internet address.

```
TCP = 8001
UDP = 8002

Public-Port-Range |  Target IP   | Target Port Range | Protocol
    8001-8002     | IPv4 Address |    8001-8002      |   Both
    8001-8002     | real Address |    8001-8002      |   Both
```

So why is the client not connecting? Is it my port forwarding or could my ISP be blocking this somehow?

Like I said, if I use localhost (127.0.0.1) for my client to connect to the server everything works as expected. When I try to connect with my dynamic DNS I get a KryoNet message that it is connecting to my "real" IP address in the console:

```
00:00  INFO: Connecting: my.dynamic.dns/XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8001/8002
```

But after the 5000ms timeout it fails to connect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to connect from within the same network it won't work. You can't access your own external IP.

You can use a port forward tester website, there's loads around, to check that the ports are open and accepting traffic, but for a true test you'll need to attempt to connect from another internet connection altogether.

Comment: Oh and on a side note there's no harm in showing what ports you're forwarding when you haven't provided your external IP.

Comment: When I had my port forwarding for my external IP address I got access refused. When I removed that it times out for every port I try even the standard ports. I have my firewall disabled.

Comment: I actually did not know my PC should actively be listening to a port for those tools to see if that port is opened. So after I factory reset my router and figured that out I setup a clean port forwarding, started my server app and the web tool told me that the port is open. Then I tried my client app and now it works as I expected. So I'm not sure what it was, the router might just needed that factory reset.

Answer (score 2):

As @Deadly-Bagel has pointed out, your modem/router may not be permitting NAT loopback i.e the ability for your LAN clients to access services (such as a web server) via your own public IP.

Resource: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#NAT_loopback

What's probably happening is

1. Your Kryo client is connecting to your DDNS server (by its URL)
2. The DDNS service (DynDNS, for example) tells your Kryo Client what the IP of the domain is (which is your own public IP).
3. Your Kryo Client then tries to connect to your own public IP and fails because your modem/router can't loopback (and then forward) the request back to your Kryo Server.

There are a few possible solutions to this:

1. Change your modem/router to one that has NAT loopback
2. Edit the computer you are using's `hosts` file to point your DDNS URL to `127.0.0.1` to give the effect of it talking to your DDNS service.
3. If your Kryo Server is on a different computer to your Kryo Client then you could tether the Kryo Client PC to, for example, your mobile phone and use your 3G connection to test your client's connection to the server.

On another note, you shouldn't do port forwards and put your public IP as the LAN IP - it doesn't work like that. The whole point of port forwarding is for WAN-side requests to be directed to a LAN-side device.

Comment: I just got it to work. After I did a factory reset, figured out I need a program that actively listens to the port to see if a port is open with those web tools it started to work. I can start my server and connect to it using the client app on the same machine using the dns provided by noip.com.